# Internal Server Error 500 using Apache, Django and mod_wsgi

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi, virtualhost

I'm trying to run a Django application on port 8000 of a server. (port 80 is occupied by WordPress) And I'm getting an internal server error when I visit :8000 extension of the website.

Here is the wsgi.py located at /var/www/admin

```
# wsgi.py

import os
import sys
import site

# Add the site-packages of the chosen virtualenv to work with
site.addsitedir('home/ubuntu/DjangoApp/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages')

# Add the app's directory to the PYTHONPATH
sys.path.append('/home/DjangoApp/tnttauburn')
sys.path.append('/home/DjangoApp/tnttauburn/tnttauburn')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'tnttauburn.settings'

# Activate your virtual env
activate_env=os.path.expanduser("home/ubuntu/DjangoApp/env/bin/activate_this.py")
execfile(activate_env, dict(__file__=activate_env))

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Here is the apache config file at /etc/apache2/sites-available/admin.conf

```
Listen 8000

<VirtualHost *:8000>
    ServerName tnttauburn.org
DocumentRoot /var/www/admin
<Directory /var/www/admin/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/admin/wsgi.py

<Directory /var/www/admin/tnttauburn>
<Files wsgi.py>
    Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
```

I thought I had all of my paths correct, but something is obviously misconfigured.

Also in Django Project settings

```
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', 'www.tnttauburn.org']
```

Comment: What are the permissions to the wsgi.py file ?

Comment: currently user: ubuntu:ubuntu should I give permission to www-data?

Comment: it depends if Apache2 runs with the ubuntu user or not :) try a `$ chown -R www-data:www-data` on the admin folder and test it.

Comment: Also tail the error log file when you restart Apache2: `$ tail -f /var/log/apache2/errors.log` <- not sure the error log file uses that name...

Comment: Can u turn your DEBUG to False at first and tell us the result ?

Comment: I guess I should of dug through the error log before posting this. I had an incorrect directory pointing to my virtual env. Thanks bchhun